# How can I bind to a static value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `MultiBinding`, with 1 of the bindings, I want to use a static value eg. 1 or 0.33 how can I do that? also when I am at it, I want to bind to the value 1/3 = 0.33333... can I have an expression?

```
<!-- not correct syntax, but something like this is what I want to acheive -->
<Binding Value="1" />
```

### UPDATE

I tried something like

```
<Binding Path="NonExistantValue" FallbackValue="0" />
```

But it fails ... in a "clean" app it works tho ...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found the answer

```
<!-- in resources -->
<sys:Single x:Key="Single0">0</sys:Single>

<!-- in multibinding -->
<Binding Source="{StaticResource Single0}" />
```

I am abit confused as to why `Single` is a `float`, why the difference in names?

Comment: `Single` describes the type of `float`; it's single-precision float point number occupying 32 bits, as opposed to a `double`, which occupies 64 bits.